# How can I check if the values were changed after an update?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, sql-update

Assuming I do something like the following:

```
my $rows = $dbh->do("UPDATE MYTABLE SET amount=1200 WHERE id =123");
```

The `$rows` returns 1 even with the amount is *already* 1200. So it is considered an updated row.
My question is: Is there a way to check if an update actually changed the values in a row besides doing a query before the update?

Answer (score 11):

Change the SQL query to:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET amount=1200 WHERE id = 123 AND amount <> 1200
```

The table will be identical, but it returns the number of rows that actually changed.

Comment: No need to change the query since MySQL already tracks both the number of rows matched in an `UPDATE` *and* the number of rows actually changed. You just need to tell it which value to report, which you can do with [`mysql_client_found_rows`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#mysql_client_found_rows) in DBD::mysql.

Comment: Yes, but my solution has the advantage of being vendor-independent.

Answer (score 2):

By default, [DBD::mysql](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3amysql) returns the number of rows *matched* in an `UPDATE`, not the number of rows physically changed. You can change this behavior by disabling [`mysql_client_found_rows`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3amysql#mysql_client_found_rows) in your call to `connect`:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:;mysql_client_found_rows=0";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`Twinkles` answer is correct, but you should create a statement handle using `prepare` and then `execute` most of your database queries.

In this case you would write

```
my $update_if_changed = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE mytable SET amount = ? WHERE id = ? AND amount != ?')
```

and subsequently

```
$update_if_changed->execute($amount, $id, $amount)
```